# Angular 4 dynamic component

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to have an array of components and then display them iteratively, in a parent component? I'm looking for something like this:

```
components: Component[];
currentIndex = 0;
currentComponent;


nextComponent() {
   this.currentComponent = this.components[currentIndex++];
   display();

}

display() {
//loading component here
}
```

I have looked into Dynamic Component Loader: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#final-ad-banner
But i have issues with this line

```
 this.components.push(new ConfigContainer(GlassTypeComponent, ''));
```

This is ConfigContainer

```
 export class ConfigContainer {

   constructor(public component: Type<any>, public data: any) {}

}
```

This is GlassTypeComponent

```
export class GlassTypeComponent implements OnInit {

 glasses: Glass[];

 constructor(public dialog: MdDialog, private configService: 
  ConfigurationService) { }

  //and methods..
}
```

creating this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all
>   parameters for GlassTypeComponent: ([object Object], ?). Error: Can't
>   resolve all parameters for GlassTypeComponent: ([object Object], ?).
>       at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1690)

This error is probably due to the constructor

Comment: Is your `GlassTypeComponent` declared as an `entryComponent` on your module?

Comment: Yes, that is not the problem.

Comment: Are all parameters for the GlassTypeComponent marked as @Injectable?